# Stratified sampling with Random Forests in R

Tags: r

I read the following in the documentation of `randomForest`:

> strata: A (factor) variable that is used for stratified sampling.
>
> sampsize: Size(s) of sample to draw.  For classification, if sampsize
>             is a vector of the length the number of strata, then sampling
>             is stratified by strata, and the elements of sampsize
>             indicate the numbers to be drawn from the strata.

For reference, the interface to the function is given by:

```
 randomForest(x, y=NULL,  xtest=NULL, ytest=NULL, ntree=500,
              mtry=if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y))
              max(floor(ncol(x)/3), 1) else floor(sqrt(ncol(x))),
              replace=TRUE, classwt=NULL, cutoff, strata,
              sampsize = if (replace) nrow(x) else ceiling(.632*nrow(x)),
              nodesize = if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y)) 5 else 1,
              maxnodes = NULL,
              importance=FALSE, localImp=FALSE, nPerm=1,
              proximity, oob.prox=proximity,
              norm.votes=TRUE, do.trace=FALSE,
              keep.forest=!is.null(y) && is.null(xtest), corr.bias=FALSE,
              keep.inbag=FALSE, ...)
```

My question is: How exactly would one use `strata`  and `sampsize`? Here is a minimal working example where I would like to test these parameters:

```
library(randomForest)
iris = read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", sep = ",", header = FALSE)
names(iris) = c("sepal.length", "sepal.width", "petal.length", "petal.width", "iris.type")

model = randomForest(iris.type ~ sepal.length + sepal.width, data = iris)

> model
500 samples
  6 predictors
  2 classes: 'Y0', 'Y1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrap (7 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 477, 477, 477, 477, 477, 477, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  ROC    Sens  Spec  ROC SD  Sens SD  Spec SD
  2     0.763  1     0     0.156   0        0      
  4     0.782  1     0     0.231   0        0      
  6     0.847  1     0     0.173   0        0      

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 6.
```

I come to these parameters since I would like RF to use bootstrap samples that respect the proportion of positives to negatives in my data.

[This other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704681/random-forest-with-classes-that-are-very-unbalanced), started a discussion on the topic, but it was settled without clarifying how one would use these parameters.

Comment: Was the example code in `?randomForest` that demonstrates stratified sampling not clear enough for you?

Comment: Thanks @joran. The example provided in the documentation uses `sampsize`  but not `strata`. The documentation only says: `strata: A (factor) variable that is used for stratified sampling`. The word `"used"` is unclear to me in this context. Perhaps because I am relatively new to stratified sampling and R.

Comment: It will probably uses the response variable by default, if you don't supply one. If you want different strata than the response variable, you'd supply it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't this just be something like:

```
model = randomForest(iris.type ~ sepal.length + sepal.width, 
                     data = iris, 
                     sampsize=c(10,10,10), strata=iris$iris.type)
```

I did try  `..., strata=iristype` and `..., strata='iristype'` but apparently the code was not written to interpret that value in the environment of the 'data' argument. I used the outcome variable because it is the only factor variable in that dataset, but I do not think it needs to be the outcome variable. In point of fact I think it definitely should NOT be the outcome variable. This particular model would be expected to product useless output and is only presented to test syntax.

Comment: How are the elements of sampsize associated with each stratum? Order of levels?

Comment: Hi Antonio; The code in randomForest.default will turn a non-factor strata-argument into a factor, and then samples within levels, so it appears the answer is "yes".