# Weight response with sampsize for unbalanced data in randomForest

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, adaboost

I am new to machine learning and R.

I tried to fit some models including trees, boosted trees, random forests, ada boosting, svm, and logistic regression with R.

In my case, probability that the rare event (class 1) occurs in the training data is 0.0075.

In the trees and boosted trees training, I added a weight parameter into a model i.e. weight class 0 with 1 and class 1 with sqrt(1/0.0075). Is that a correct way to do this?

I have some issue with random forest. I searched for using sampsize in order to deal with unbalanced data like this.

However, I am not quite sure how to give proper weight to each class.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704681/random-forest-with-classes-that-are-very-unbalanced) and there is a suggestion to reduce imbalance ratio down. How do I chose the proper one?

Also, I have no idea how to include weights in ada boosting and logistic regression.

Comment: You may want to try to narrow down your question a bit more. As it stands now, it'd be hard to write a good answer to this question: [ask]

Comment: I would like to know how to properly specify sampsize parameter in random forest that will fit with unbalanced data which is class 0:class 1 ~ 133:1.

Comment: Hmm, you might update to title to match that a bit better. It'll help draw attention to the question.