# Which Machine Learning Algo to use for click/no-click prediction against many nominal variables

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, prediction

I am an absolute noob in machine learning. I have a data set with values like:

`state`

`hour`

`day of the week`,

`device platform`,

`user agent`,

Along with yes or no based on whether there was a click or not.

This data has mostly string values as can be infered from the headers. They are a lot in number as well, for data like zip, device platform id etc.

Also the number of clicked records is a very small number in comparison to number of non-clicked records.

So, based on these results, how should I train the model?
Also what algorithm - regression, classification or decision trees should I implement?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What exactly would you like to algorithm to do? What is the end goal of it, that is?

Comment: end goal is to predict whether click will happen based on values of city, state, device, browser etc.

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of data where the decision region can be non-linear, with string features and imbalance between number of positive and negative classes(click/non-click):
Support vector data description(SVDD) or also called SVM based anomaly detection can be a good choice. 
For a quick start use SVDD in the libSVM library, to quickly check if its worth a try. (Make sure you chose the proper kernel and kernel parameters before jumping to conclusion of whether or not the method is working.)

Make sure that there is some pattern, I cannot convince myself why there should be one at all.
If there is no underlying pattern there is nothing you can do to predict it better than any random model.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look through [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/talks/picasso-minicourse.pdf) article, it sheds some light on the basics of Machine learning, how it works, and some different methods. Specifically, pay attention to slides 8 - 25/26.

You can also have a quick look at [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). They have some very useful tools for Machine learning and data mining. Let me know if you need any clarifications on these!

Answer (score 0):

This is a classification problem where you are interested in predicting whether a record was clicked or not. Clicks (minority class) and non clicks (majority class) form the two classes for this classification problem. Since the dataset is imbalanced (# of instances of majority class >> # of instances of minority class), the following version of random forests works well in practice:

- create each tree in the random forest on a different stratified sample of the entire dataset. Each stratified sample is created by combining i) downsampled rows of the majority class to have as many rows as there are in the minority class, and ii) sampled rows (as many rows in the minority class) with replacement from the minority class.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704681/random-forest-with-classes-that-are-very-unbalanced?rq=1) for how to use the randomForest package in R to do this.

For imbalanced datasets, it is imperative to use area under the ROC curve as the metric to optimize rather than the accuracy.

Finally, it might be useful to create other important features from the user agent. For example OS, browser_name, mobile/ desktop can all be learnt from the user agent and might be useful features to predict clicks/ non-clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, some questions
-I did parse user agent into device, browser os etc, giving more categorical variables. R can generate a random forest till 32 levels only, is there a way to bring the large set to only this much?
Also, being not very well versed in this field, could you tell me a link or tut on how to create trees in a random forest like the way mentioned in your method.

Comment: Also, going through some papers I saw a lot of suggestions for logistic regression, is that also a viable choice?

Comment: Logistic Regression is a parametric model and depending on the data, might work well for you. I would suggest to run a non-parametric model like random forest in order to ensure there is some non linearity that the logistic regression model is not picking on.

Comment: @richi_18007: To create stratified samples with the radomForest package in R, you can use the sampsize option with it. The [example](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-October/081557.html) explains how to create samples from the entire dataset while building each tree.